# DateTime.ParseExact Method not recognizing "Z" as UTC time

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to read log files, extracting timestamps as datetime objects. Some of these times are in the UTC format, with a trailing "Z". I have included "K" in our format, however, the datetime is still not recognized as UTC. 
Instead, it is seen as unspecified.

A snippet of the code below:

```
string teststring = line.Substring(OffsetStart, format.Length);
DateTime datePlaceholder;

if (DateTime.TryParseExact(teststring, format, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out datePlaceholder))
{
    Format = format;
    OffsetEnd = OffsetStart + format.Length;
    FormatLen = format.Length;
        return datePlaceholder;
    break;
}
```

I iterate through a few different format strings, for example, here is one:

```
yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffK
```

Any insight is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you will need to use:

```
System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal
```

Instead of

```
System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None
```

So the entire line would be:

```
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(teststring, format, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal, out datePlaceholder))
{do whatever}
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you :)

Comment: `AdjustToUniversal` will *always* adjust the value to UTC.  It's not necessarily wrong, but if the input strings might vary then instead consider `RoundTripKind`, which will adjust *if* the input string is in UTC (in this format, when the `Z` is present in the position marked with the `K` specifier).